# Positioning an element with jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript

I am trying to create an element and position it on top of a 2nd element. What I want is for the new element to be placed at a specific location on the main element offset from the top left. When I run the code bellow (Coffeescript) it puts the div more or less in the middle but a bit bellow that. It should be in the upper left, I know I must be doing something wrong but I have no idea what/

```
              $("<div>")                      
                    .appendTo(window.targetElement)
                    .position(
                            my                 : "top left"
                            at                 : "top left"
                            of                 : window.targetElement
                            offset             : "#{placeholder.left} #{placeholder.top}"
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal component must come before the vertical component in `my` and `at`:

```
$('<div>')
    .appendTo(window.targetElement)
    .position(
        my:     'left top'
        at:     'left top'
        of:     window.targetElement
        offset: "#{placeholder.left} #{placeholder.top}"
    )
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WZc4r/

From the [fine manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/):

> **at**
>   Defines which position on the element being positioned to align with the target element: *"horizontal vertical"* alignment. [...]

Emphasis mine. The demo code also puts the horizontal part first:

```
$( ".positionable" ).position({
    of: $( "#parent" ),
    my: $( "#my_horizontal" ).val() + " " + $( "#my_vertical" ).val(),
    at: $( "#at_horizontal" ).val() + " " + $( "#at_vertical" ).val(),
    //...
```

I'd guess that the order matters because they want `my` and `at` to match `offset` but `offset` is just two numbers.